# Post request does not work in Scrapy. Works in Postman. Where am I wrong?

Tags: python, scrapy, postman

I use `scrapy.FormRequest.from_response` to Post. I am getting through captcha and all data is in place but Do not get the table I expect.
[image: But this message]
Here is my payload

```
{
  'captcha': '680336',
  'districtCode': '714',
  'sroVal': 'TADIKONDA(714)',
  'selectedSroId': 'null',
  'sroId': '7',
  'path': '/APCARDECClient',
  'regyear': '2018',
  'docSel': '1',
  'doct': '861'
}
```

And headers I used for Post request.

```
{
  'origin': 'http://registration.ap.gov.in',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,uk;q=0.7',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xh tml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'referer': 'http://registration.ap.gov.in/APCARDECClient/ecSearchByDocAu to.jsp?distcode=&distname=&srocode=&sroname=',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36',
  'dnt': '1',
  'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=dQJTbqhpYdg1PMjJZkYT9bTyLLnMqV43zxj2sws1gZ2fQ8fJn0CQ!-392092779',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urle ncoded'
}
```

When I use the same data to mimic Post in Postman it works fine and I recieve the table as expected.
[image: Postman results]
Here is payload from Postman:

```
captcha:331683
districtCode:7
docSel:1
doct:861
path:/APCARDECClient
regyear:2018
selectedSroId:null
sroId:714
sroVal:TADIKONDA(714)
```

and headers from Postman:

```
Origin:http://registration.ap.gov.in
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
DNT:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer:http://registration.ap.gov.in/APCARDECClient/FetchHelpDetails
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,uk;q=0.7
Cookie:JSESSIONID=dQJTbqhpYdg1PMjJZkYT9bTyLLnMqV43zxj2sws1gZ2fQ8fJn0CQ!-392092779
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Please point me where am I wrong?
The only possibility I see is this line:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Do  I need to do smth explicit in Scrapy to encode the payload like this?

P.S. When I use bare

```
yield scrapy.Request(url, method ="POST",  body=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers,  callback = self.details1)
```

I am getting starting page with empty fields.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `FormRequest` - it just injects some headers and has some body shortcuts. If you are replicating a request just use barebones `Request`.

```
import headers
headers = {
    # make sure Content Type is set
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    # some other headers
}
payload = """foobar"""
Request(
    url,
    headers=headers,
    method='POST',
    body=payload,
)
```

Comment: if I do so I receive empty forms (like when you first visit the page)

Comment: Then you're missing something. Whether it's a header or part of payload. Oh and check my edit in `Request` I've made a type there, payload should go to `body`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So the problem was in  `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',`
I noticed it in the very beginning but did not pay any further attention. So Stupid.
In order to pass this page the payload should be `urlencoded` as indicated by `Content_Type`.
Here is how to do that.

```
import urllib

payload = {'captcha': '865944',
                 'sroVal': 'TADIKONDA(714)',
                 'sroId': '714',
                 'regyear': '2017', 
                 'doct': '1',
                 'districtCode': '7',
                 'path': '/APCARDECClient',
                 'selectedSroId': 'null',
                 'docSel': '1',
           }

payload = urllib.urlencode(payload)

yield scrapy.Request(url, method ="POST",  body=payload ,headers=headers,  
                     callback = self.details1)
```